# SuperSU or Superuser binary

Tags: installation, supersu

Can I add the superuser binary without a custom recovery?
Is there a way to force the binary install through terminal or  PC or app?

Comment: You can't write to `/system` normally. PC/app one-click rooters just use an exploit to forcefully open it up.

Comment: @AndyYan Nowadays one-click rooters flash a custom recovery (usually modded CWM) then their own root zip.

Comment: @iBug Really? I'm talking about the likes of KingRoot, KingoRoot, iRoot, etc. Those won't even need a reboot.

Comment: @AndyYan Modern phones no longer have such exploits so even the rooters you mentioned will have to rec+root. They only work "*originally*" on older exploitable phones.

Comment: @AndyYan I've also seen an alternative to grant `adbd` with root privileges by modifying `/boot` used by a few softwares, but more that uses this method are scripts and tools from BBSs.

Comment: @iBug Yeah I know about the lack of exploits, but I've never seen any of them migrate to this "classic" route as of yet, because that would mean they have to craft a recovery for *every* device they want to target, which I doubt those guys with quick money in mind would do. Modifying `/boot` is beyond mention as it's even more device-specific.

Comment: @AndyYan Modifying `/boot` is slightly different from directly flashing a new precompiled `boot.img`, as SuperSU does in "Systemless root". Also, a generic recovery doesn't seem *that* hard to make, as you can identify partitions with their partition name (not volume label). You can check out Shuame Sprite for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57734/discussion-between-andy-yan-and-ibug).

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, but it depends on your device. For example, if you have an older non-updated Amazon device, you can usually root it with as little as an app install. For devices that haven't been exploited yet, however, there's little hope besides asking the community on xda and such very very nicely. It's a good idea to look for "bootloader unlockable" devices when you're looking to purchase a new Android device, to show the corporations that people want this.